# Closed subspace of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

> Is the subspace of continuous functions $C[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ closed with the metric
>
> $$ d(f,g) = \max|f(x)-g(x)|? $$

Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any function $g\in C[0,1]$ not in the given subspace will have positive distance from the subspace (at least $|g(0)|$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|f_n(0) - f(0)|\leq d(f_n, f)$.